# MySQL views performance with select * from tablename definition

Tags: mysql, view, merge

I have created views with following generic definition on all of my tables required for reporting

```
select * from tablename
```

Ideally views with this definition should use merge algorithm.

Can someone please tell me if the performance of these views with the above definition will be comparable to the physical tables?

Comment: Thanks for the link...but my question is about mysql and its a different db than SQL server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/31/derived-tables-and-views-performance/).

By above report, `derived table` shows poor performance than `table`, while simple `view` works good. But if you run a query with `ORDER` or `WHERE` on view, it will be slower than naive table. (see comments on the link )

And use `EXPLAIN` to checkout your queries between view and table.